# I want the two bars to run first and in the middle the banner

Tags: python

```
from pyfiglet import figlet_format as pyfiglet
import time,sys

banner = pyfiglet("Banner")

#I want the two texts to be executed and finally the banner to be executed

print ("\n━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━")

for i in banner:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print (i,end="")
    time.sleep(00.01)

print ("━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━")
```

I want the two bars to appear first and then the banner

Comment: Include an example of your expected output.

Comment: Well, let the two bars be printed first, after that I want the banner to appear inside those two bars

Comment: If you print the two bars first, they will appear above the banner, is this what you want.  Please show us an example of what your desired output would look like.

Comment: first print those two bars without the banner then in the center of the two already printed bars run inside

Comment: Add a \n to your last print? `print ("\n━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━")`

Answer (score 0):

Checking to some possibilities to delay the print of the `pyfiglet` text or to collect the second line in the pile in some place where you can get it back when you need it, the only answer that i can find is that it can´t be possible in a agil way.

Print statements pile output into stdout in the order the code was written. Top to bottom. So if you wrote the `pyfiglet` element before it will print it before. That´s the way the code is interpreted.

The output of the console is a line for line rendition of the elements was piled into stdout, and the order due to the line were it had been written. It can´t be change, because it maintains chronology.

You could check how print function itself works, and try to adapt to your own goal, but it is not recommended tampering with standard library functions.